# How can I concatenate two bytes in java?

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, byte, bucket

I have an integer called `writePos` that takes a value between `[0,1023]`. I need to store it in the last two bytes of a byte array called `bucket`. So, I figure I need to represent it as a concatenation of the array's last two bytes.

1. How would I go about breaking down `writePos` into two bytes that, when concatenated and cast into an `int`, produces `writePos` again?
2. How would I go about concatenating once I get it broken down into the bytes?

Comment: For what purpose? If you're dealing with I/O, have a look at `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream.`

Comment: I'm dealing with buckets/buffers, and trying to make note of where the first available position for writing in the bucket is. The bucket length is 1023 bits. So we have two bytes in the end of my array of bytes (length 1023 as I mentioned) indicated where that index is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be covered high-level by a ByteBuffer.

```
short loc = (short) writeLocation;

byte[] bucket = ...
int idex = bucket.length - 2;
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bucket);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE__ENDIAN); // Optional
buf.putShort(index, loc);

writeLocation = buf.getShort(index);
```

The order can be specified, or left to the default (BIG_ENDIAN).

1. The ByteBuffer wraps the original byte array, and changes to ByteBuffer effect on the byte array too.
2. One can use sequential writing and reading an positioning (seek), but here I use overloaded methods for immediate positioning with `index`.
3. `putShort` writes to the byte array, modifying two bytes, a short.
4. `getShort` reads a short from the byte array, which can be put in an int.

---

***Explanation***

A `short` in java is a two-byte (signed) integral number. And that is what is meant. The order is whether LITTLE_ENDIAN: least significant byte first (n % 256, n / 256) or big endian.

Comment: I think this is the answer I need, because my project is using a bytebuffer. I'm not sure what is going on in your answer, though. How does this account for both the last and second to last byte of my bucket?

Comment: Added an explanation; java `short` instead of `int`being defined as 2 bytes.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I would have loved a little more understanding of what's happening. It seems like the wrap function adds functionality to the byte array you give it, and actually modifies its contents. Is that true?

Comment: You are so right `wrap` implies that the passed data, byte array, is the backing store of the byte buffer. Mentioned it now a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise operations.

To byte:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
// This uses a bitwise and (&) to take only the last 8 bits of i
byte[0] = (byte)(i & 0xff); 
// This uses a bitwise and (&) to take the 9th to 16th bits of i
// It then uses a right shift (>>)  then move them right 8 bits
byte[1] = (byte)((i & 0xff00) >> 8);from byte:
```

To go back the other way

```
// This just reverses the shift, no need for masking.
// The & here is used to handle complications coming from the sign bit that
// will otherwise be moved as the bytes are combined together and converted
// into an int
i = (byte[0] & 0xFF)+(byte[1] & 0xFF)<<8;
```

There is a working example here of some of the conversions that you can play around with: 
http://ideone.com/eRzsun

Comment: Not sure I follow exactly what is happening. Would you mind explaining in terms of my variables what role that code plays? I will play with it.

Comment: Beware that when a byte is cast into an int, it gets sign-extended, i.e. half of the byte values is taken as negative numbers....

Comment: @Bram Yes, I just had to quickly refresh my memory - should have all the correct shifts etc now

Comment: @Brandon see answer now, added more explanation

Comment: `byte[] bytes = new byte[2];byte[0] = (byte)i;byte[1] = (byte)(i >>> 8);` is OK because assignment from int to byte does not change any bits.

Comment: @fredt Yes, I prefer to write it like this though as an answer since it is clearer what is happening

Comment: I'm getting huge numbers when I do this. Only get bigger and bigger.

Comment: @Brandon Take a look at my working example on the ideone link, play around with that and you should be able to get something working out of it

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the integer into two bytes. The high and the low byte. Following your description it's stored as bug endian in the array.

```
int writeLocation = 511;
byte[] bucket = new byte[10];
// range checks must be done before
// bitwise right rotation by 8 bits
bucket[8] = (byte) (writeLocation >> 8); // the high byte
bucket[9] = (byte) (writeLocation & 0xFF); // the low byte

System.out.println("bytes = " + Arrays.toString(bucket));

// convert back the integer value 511 from the two bytes
bucket[8] = 1;
bucket[9] = (byte) (0xFF);
// the high byte will bit bitwise left rotated
// the low byte will be converted into an int
// and only the last 8 bits will be added
writeLocation = (bucket[8] << 8) + (((int) bucket[9]) &  0xFF);
System.out.println("writeLocation = " + writeLocation);
```